# WPF closing all windows when user closes one of them

Tags: wpf

There's a WPF application with multiple windows. Initially there's only one window. User may go to next windows while previous are hidden. When they return back, hidden windows appear again. The problem is that when user closes some window, the hidden ones continue to run as processes. Is it possible to close all of them when user closes any.

Comment: do you mean closing the application..?

Comment: @Sergey I went through your previous question of multiple windows. If this is the same application, I strongly suggest you what others in that question have. Use page navigation if possible, as it is designed for exactly the purpose you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, man, but I've already done it with windows and not much time is left. I wish I could've done it with pages, now I see.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to terminate an application with all windows, you can call [`App.Current.Shutdown();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx). If you want call this on closing of any window, register to the [Window.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) event and call `App.Current.Shutdown();` there in.

Through App.Current.Windows you have access to all Window-instances. You also can [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx) them manually.

Comment: But if put it in every `Window.Closed` Is that will fire some event multiple times?  Like WPF `App.OnExit` event.