# WPF close all window from the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have login window. From this login window, i am intializing the main window. 
Once login successfully happened, i close the login window. 
Now i am having two other windows, which i am calling from Main Window.
Once i close the main Window, I am able to close the other two windows as well as Main Window.
But program still runs in memory. I have to close it manually from the Visual Studio. 
How should i close the Program all instances fully??
This is the Main window Close Event code.

```
private void usimClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   newScreen2.Close();
   newScreen3.Close();  
   this.Close();                        
}
```

This is my Login Window Code. Once the user click on the submit button.

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (txtUserName.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            errormessage.Text = "Please Enter UserName";
            txtUserName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {                
            LoginStatus _status = _Login.LoginUsimgClient(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password.ToString());

            if (_status.BoolLoginstatus)
            {
                mainWindow.RunApplication();
                string struserName = _status.StringUserFirstName;
                mainWindow.userName.Text = "Welcome " + struserName;
                mainWindow.Show();
                this.Close();                    
            }
            else
            {
                errormessage.Text = _status.StringErrorDescription;
                txtUserName.Text = String.Empty;
                txtPassword.Password = String.Empty;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: i think the mainWindow is a property of your login window, so it holds the login window in memory

Comment: yes. i think so. How should i resolve it then?

Comment: instead of closing it, if i hide my login window 


 this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

But from Main Window how should i close the Login Window?

Comment: try to show and handle your login stuff at the OnStartup event of the App

Comment: If I understand that your main window is member of login window, then that is not correct. You should create your login window in your App class on startup event and when login functionality is done instantiate main window and show it. Other windows modal/not should have main window as parent so that they are collected when main window is closed.

Comment: see this if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982116/wpf-closing-all-windows-when-user-closes-one-of-them

Comment: There were some ForeGroundThread running in other window. I closed them. Now i am able to close all windows. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you starting point is your MainWindow, then just start there.

Firstly, host the LoginForm in your MainWindow, and show it using ShowDialog() to force the user to interact with the LoginForm. Return the result of a successful/unsuccessful interaction to the MainForm.

```
    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new LoginForm();
        var result = form.ShowDialog();

        if (result ?? false)
        {
            // Carry on opening up other windows
        }
        else
        {
            // Show some kind of error message to the user and shut down
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, technically your LoginForm is hosting your MainForm which is, frankly, odd.

Answer (score 7):

Try `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx)

> Calling Shutdown explicitly causes an application to shut down,
> regardless of the ShutdownMode setting. However, if ShutdownMode is
> set to OnExplicitShutdown, you must call Shutdown to shut down an
> application.
>
> Important note
>
> When Shutdown is called, the application will shut down irrespective
> of whether the Closing event of any open windows is canceled.
>
> This method can be called only from the thread that created the
> Application object.

Answer (score 4):

You can close all windows using this

```
App.Current.Shutdown();
```

or

you can manually close it

```
Window parentwin = Window.GetWindow();
parentwin.Close();
```

Comment: There were some ForeGroundThread running in other window. I closed them. Now  i am able to close all windows.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer here: [How to close wpf window from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800182/how-to-close-wpf-window-from-another-project/16800387#16800387)

An Application.Current.Shutdown() will stop the application in a very abrupt way.

It is better to gracefully keep track of the windows and close them.